# Glob-Patterns for positive floating point numbers

Tags: bash, numbers, glob

I want to use glob-patterns to match positive floating point numbers.

Would these be correct?

```
pitg='?(+)*([0-9])'
pfxp='?(+)*([0-9])?([.,])+([0-9])'
pflp='?(+)*([0-9])?([.,])+([0-9])?([eE]?([-+])+([0-9]))'

pitg to match 3 345 -98
pfxp to match 1.234 0.234 .345 -0.23 -45.56 3 345 -98
pflp to match -1.234E07 345.23E-8
```

How can they be used in a condition construct?

For regular expressions one uses

```
if [[ $num =~ $regex ]]; then
```

For globshell patterns, is it to be done with

```
if [[ $num == $gptrn ]]; then
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what you're trying to match and not-match? BTW, these are extended globs; they require `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
patt='?(+)@(+([0-9])?(.*([0-9]))|*([0-9]).+([0-9]))?([eE]?([+-])+([0-9]))'
```

testing

```sh
for num in 3.14 +3.14 100 +100 .1 +.1; do
  [[ $num == $patt ]] || echo "$num does not match"
done
for num in 3.14e10 3.14E-4 3.14e+010; do
  [[ $num == $patt ]] || echo "$num does not match"
done
```

Happily, no output.

Note that `extglob` is automatically on for pattern matching within `[[...]]`

> When the ‘`==`’ and ‘`!=`’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), **as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled**.

ref https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

---

Breaking down that pattern:

```
?(+)@(+([0-9])?(.*([0-9]))|*([0-9]).+([0-9]))

?(+)                                            # optional +
    @(                                          # one of:
      +([0-9])?(         )                      # mandatory digits, optionally followed by ...
                .*([0-9])                       # ... a dot and optional digits
                          |                     # or
                           *([0-9])             # optional digits followed by...
                                   .+([0-9])    # ... mandatory dot and digits
                                            )
```

(too wide)
followed optionally by the exponent

```
?([eE]?([+-])+([0-9]))
```

Comment: _Note that extglob is automatically on for pattern matching within [[...]]_ **No it doesn't:** `shopt -u extglob; [[ 1 == +(1) ]]` gives `-bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token '('`, in macOS bash

Comment: I see. Looks like this changed in bash 4.1 -- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.2#n713

Comment: The change is a great thing.  I love it.